# Powershell job execution handle batch processing properly without waiting for whole batch to finish

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm using PowerShell job to process activity in parallel. I attached a sample code of it below.

```
Function Wait-UntilJobFailOrSuccess {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [System.Management.Automation.Job[]]$Job
    )
    begin {
        $jobs = @()
        $abort = $false
    }
    process {
        $jobs += $Job
    }
    end {

        while ('Running' -In $jobs.State) {
            if ('Failed' -in $jobs.State) {
                $jobs | Stop-Job 
                $abort = $true
                break
            }
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
        }

        foreach ($job in $jobs) {
            if ($job.State -eq 'Failed') {
                $job.ChildJobs | ForEach-Object {
                    Write-Host ($_.JobStateInfo.Reason.Message) -ForegroundColor Red
                }
            }
            else {

                Write-Host "$($job.Name) $($job.State) successfully"
            }
        }

        if ($abort) {
            exit 1
        }
    }
}
```

The above method will be used for a job which will be parallelly executed.

```
$packageSpecs | ForEach-Object -Begin {
    $job = @()
} -Process {
    $builditem = $_ 
   $job += Start-Job -Name $("Pack" + $builditem.name) -ScriptBlock $scriptoExecute -ArgumentList $args
    if ($job.Count -eq $maxNumberOfThread) {
        $job |Wait-UntilJobFailOrSuccess
        $job = @()
    }
} -End {

    if ($job.Count -gt 0) {
        $job |Wait-UntilJobFailOrSuccess
        $job = @()
    }

}
```

If you see above code  I'm running the job based on the number of CPU present in a machine,  $maxNumberOfThread contain number of logical processes allowed in the system.

Now I will tell you my problem statement.

Suppose  $maxNumberOfThread =4. It will process 4 jobs at a time. What I want is if I am processing 4 jobs and anyone of the job is finished. I should be able to queue the next one. At present it is processing all 4 job then next batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few tweaks, i cut out the Wait-UntilJobFailOrSuccess function. But this should work. Try and let me know. If it works you then made can tweak it for your function.

```
 $packageSpecs | ForEach-Object -Begin {
     $job = @()
 } -Process {
     $builditem = $_ 
     $job += Start-Job -Name $("Pack" + $builditem.name) -ScriptBlock $scriptoExecute -ArgumentList $args
     $running = @($job | Where-Object { $_.State -eq 'Running' })
     if ($running.Count -ge $maxNumberOfThread) {
         $running | Wait-Job -Any | Out-Null
         Write-Verbose "Waiting on jobs" -Verbose
     }  

 } -End {

     if ($job.Count -gt 0) {
         $job |Wait-UntilJobFailOrSuccess
         $job = @()
     }
 }
```

I made some changes to your function, pls let me know how it works out. The function now needs the $MaxNumberOfThread passed to it.

```
Function Wait-UntilJobFailOrSuccess {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [System.Management.Automation.Job[]]$Job,

        [Parameter()]
        [int]$maxNumberOfThread
    )
    begin {
        $jobs = @()
        $abort = $false
    }
    process {
        $jobs += $Job
        foreach ($j in $Jobs) {
            $running = @($jobs | Where-Object { $_.State -eq 'Running' })
            if ($running.Count -ge $maxNumberOfThread) {
                if ('Failed' -in $jobs.State) {
                    $jobs | Stop-Job 
                    $abort = $true
                    break
                }
                else {
                    $running | Wait-Job -Any | Out-Null
                    Write-Verbose "Waiting on jobs" -Verbose
                }
            }
            if ($abort) {
                exit 1
            }
        }
    }
    end {
        foreach ($j in $jobs) {
            if ($j.State -eq 'Failed') {
                $j.ChildJobs | ForEach-Object {
                    Write-Host ($_.JobStateInfo.Reason.Message) -ForegroundColor Red
                }
            }
            else {

                Write-Host "$($j.Name) $($j.State) successfully"
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. It work for one scenario. But another scenario it is getting failed. For example , If you see Wait-UntilJobFailOrSuccess. I was written a logic. If anyone of the job is getting failed i need to abort all the running jobs. Wait-job -Any. How do i handle that?